# What is the BigO notation on searching on a string that keeps changing for a character

Tags: java, string, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have the function below that finds the longest non repeating sub-string in a string.
I know the for loop is O(n) but what will be the additional time by searching current char in tmp string in call to function `indexOf`.

```
public static String find(String input) {
    String currentLongest = input.length() > 0 ? "" + input.charAt(0) : "";
    String tmp = currentLongest;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int index = tmp.indexOf(""+input.charAt(i));
        if (index  == -1) {
            tmp = tmp + input.charAt(i);
            if (tmp.length() > currentLongest.length())
                currentLongest = tmp;
        } else
            tmp = tmp.substring(index+1)+input.charAt(i);
    }
    return currentLongest;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `indexOf()`, and recreating `tmp` (using operator+), which both happen in every iteration, takes `O(|S|)` time, where `|S|` is the length of `tmp` in this iteration. Now, the question is is the length of `tmp` bounded?

**If your alphabet is limited** (for example, if it can contain only characters from a,b,...,z) - then the length of `tmp` is of limited size (26 in the a-z example, this comes from [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). In this case, you can say that `indexOf()` and creating a new string (by using operator +) is taking `O(1)` time, since it is creating a string with bounded size. And in this case, the algorithm takes **`O(n)`** time.

However, **if the alphabet is unlimited**, you can have an input string with no repeatitions at all.
In this case, each iteration of the loop takes `O(i)` time. This gives you.

```
1 + 2 + ... n = n (n+1)/2
```

Which is in `O(n^2)`, and the algorithm's complexity becomes **`O(n^2)`**